# UIScrollView did EndScrollingAnimation called before animation ends

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have built a keyboard with some down arrows to allow for navigation on a tableView.  When the cell the user is on reaches the bottom, I auto scroll the next cell up for them.  I had to disable the buttons during the scrolling animations because it could cause a hang, however for some reason recently, this functionality stopped working.

After investigation I noticed that its because the scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation delegate is being called multiple times before the animation actually finishes.  It seems like its called just before animation starts, the middle of the animation, and at the end.

Has anyone seen anything like this before? Or know why this would be happening?

Comment: What do you want to know about from the delegate method? When the user lifts up their finger? When the scroll view stops moving?

Comment: when the scrollView stops moving.  I need to re-enable the keyboard.  Currently its enabling too soon, and the user can spam the keys before the animation is done, and it causes weird things to happen